# Selenium not detecting an element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm coding this bot to join my school classes for me using selenium and I'm facing this issue where it goes to my conferences page and it waits for a join button to appear and press on it. At first, it wouldn't be able to find it so I scratched the idea of time and I made sure that when it opens the page the join button will be there so I did that and even put this line of code just to make sure
`join=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Join')]")))`
yet it still can't find the join button either press it even though it's visible by the eye I will link the page source under in a link if you can just tell me how to find it also I cant use the href method since it isn't stored like that it's just stored like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldxY7.png
so I'm really confused it's almost like this is an invisible element its funny because even when I do get an error I use control F on inspect element to check if I used correct XPATH and I always find it so I don't see why selenium cant please help I think I just missed something I just don't know what.

[Page Source](https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/b950eff4)

Comment: Try to use `element_to_be_clickable` instead of `presence_of_element_located`

Comment: already tried that doesnt work the problem is that it cant find the element even thought it is indeed there

Answer (score 0):

Check the presence of the element by looping and checking the presence_of_element_element_located multiple times with 2/3 seconds delay added between every consecutive check.
An analogy from python selenium-

```
for i in range(5):
    l= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-gdpr")
    time.sleep(5)
```

OR

Iterate over all the elements under the parent div and verify it using unique text/color and access it.

Comment: Might you add how to do it exactly? Like how can OP add delay and check it multiple time?

Comment: tried both of that didnt work added a time.sleep(10) between each time i think it is possible by using select frame but im not sure how but if i can tell the program to switch to frame index 1 it should work do you know how i can write than in code (python)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do Google meet automation. In that website the "join now" button is declared as a  dynamic path so, you can use the library pyautogui

```
impor pyautogui as pg
for i in range(5):
    pg.press('tab')
time.sleep(2)
pg.press('enter')
```

This code will help you to find the join now button and to click it.

Comment: i thought of that too at first but im not using google meet and the website im using doesnt support tab movement to go from one button to the other so this could work but just not on this website sadly